# Firebase Database and GenericTypeIndicator

Tags: android, database, firebase

Looked at many solutions and can't seem to find one in order to retrieve nodes as an Array

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    mDatabase.child("users").child(auth.getUid());

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};

            List<String> yourStringArray = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
            Log.w(TAG, "users array: " + yourStringArray);

}
```

In android studio I get this error on t:

```
Cannot resolve method'getValue(com.firebase.client.GenericTypeIndicator<java.util.List<java.lang.String>>)'
```

My database structure: https://gyazo.com/9f2109d3d5c699329b74d6a6ed8279e8

Alternative solution to return using getValue but cannot convert to array or list...

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    mDatabase.child("users").child(auth.getUid());

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            collectData((Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());

            Log.w(TAG, "users array: " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
}

public String collectData(Map<String, Object> value) {


    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : value.entrySet()) {

        users.add((Map.Entry) entry);

    }
    return users.toString();
}
```

but I really need it as an array as a hashmap is not suitable for my purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up versions of the Firebase client library SDKs.  You can tell by seeing this in the error message:

```
com.firebase.client.GenericTypeIndicator
```

`com.firebase` comes from an obsolete version.  You want the ones from `com.google.firebase`.  Remove the legacy SDK from your build.gradle and us only the new ones.